# QML signal handler not responding to C++ signal

Tags: c++, qml, signals

I have a simple program which incorporates signalling between QML and C++.

I currently have two cases where I need to signal from C++ to QML.

The first is from one of my source files/classes, "Search", and the second is from a different c++ source file/class, "Node".

The signals in the first case are received by a dynamically created QML object, using
`parent.dynamic_object_name = Qt.createQmlObject(QString,parent,'name');`

In this dynamic object, the following code receives the signal "someAction"

```
import Search 1.0

...

Search {
    id: search
}
Connections {
    target: search
    onSomeAction: {
        dosomething()
    }
}
```

And this has worked for me. Search is registered through qmlregistertype. And dosomething() is succesfully called.

However, in the second case, though I have made sure to make the format exactly the same, it does not work.

In this second case, I am receiving a signal from "Node.cpp". I have followed the same procedure, registering "Node" with qmlRegisterType. This time, I try to received the signal in main.qml.

```
import Node 1.0

...

Node {
    id: node
}
Connections {
    target: node
    onCreateNode: {
        newNode()
    }
}
```

No error message is thrown. Showing the program knows my signal exists, it just doesn't react to it.
I've looked around online, and I've seen that there musn't be more than one signal handler, otherwise only the last one is active. Thus, I have tried removing my signal handler in my dynamic object, however I still cannot receive the signal. Thus this is not the issue.

I have considered the possibility that my emitter is using a different instance of "Node" to the one I have registered. This was indeed the case, but after fixing, the problem remained.

Here are relevant snippets:

Node class:

```
class Node: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Node(QObject * parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void getNode(int id);
    Q_INVOKABLE void acceptedSelection(QString selection, int x, int y);
    void generateNode(int id);
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

private:
    struct nodeInfo{
        int x;
        int y;
        QString text;
        int width;
        int height;
        int fontSize;
        int color;
        int parent;
        QVector<int> children;

    };
    QVector<nodeInfo> nodeMap;

signals:
    void createNode(QString nodeData);
public slots:
};
```

Signal sent from node. Program succesfully outputs "generate called".

```
void Node::generateNode(int id)
{
    QString xpos = QString::number(nodeMap[id].x);
    QString ypos = QString::number(nodeMap[id].y);
    QString width = QString::number(nodeMap[id].width);
    QString height = QString::number(nodeMap[id].width);
    QString nodeData = QString("import QtQuick 2.0; Rectangle{x:%1;y:%2;width:%3;height:%4}").arg(
                xpos,ypos,width,height);
    qDebug()<<"generate called";
    emit createNode(nodeData);
}
```

main.qml:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:mywin
    objectName: "AppWindow"
    visible: true
    width: 1600
    height: 900
    title: qsTr("Qmap")

    Node {
        id: mynode;
    }

    Item{
        id: myitem
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus:true
        Connections {
            id: nodeconnect;
            target: mynode;
            onCreateNode:{
                console.log("hi");
            }
        }
```

To clarify, I do not understand why, in the same program, with the same implementation, one signal works and the other one doesn't. 
If I missed any required information, please tell me.
Any help is appreciated.

Complete code: 
**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

import Node 1.0
import Search 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id:mywin
    objectName: "AppWindow"
    visible: true
    width: 1600
    height: 900
    title: qsTr("Qmap")
    menuBar: MenuBar{

        Menu {
            title: "File"
            MenuItem{text: "open"}
        }
        Menu {
            title: "Edit"
            MenuItem{text:"undo"}
        }
    }
    Node {
        id: mynode;
    }

    Item{
        id: myitem
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus:true



        property int mouse_lastx: 0;
        property int mouse_lasty: 0;

        MouseArea{
            id: mousearea
            hoverEnabled: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPositionChanged: {
                myitem.mouse_lastx = mouseX
                myitem.mouse_lasty = mouseY
            }
        }

        Connections {
            id: nodeconnect;
            target: mynode;
            onCreateNode:{
                console.log("hi");
            }
        }



        Keys.onTabPressed: {

            create_rect(mouse_lastx,mouse_lasty)

        }

        property string find:"
        import QtQuick 2.0;
        import Search 1.0
        import Node 1.0
        FocusScope{
            id: scope;
            focus:true;
            x:%1;
            y:%2;

            Rectangle {
                id: suggestionBox;
                color: 'grey';
                border.width:2;
                width:200;
                height:135;
                x:-5000
                y:34
                Text {
                    id: first;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 5;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: second;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 30;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: third;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 55;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: fourth;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 80;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: fith;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 105;
                    text: '';
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: selectionBox;
                    color:'#33000000';
                    border.width:2;
                    width: 200;
                    height:25;
                    x: 0;
                    y: 0;
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id:newrect;
                color: 'grey';
                border.width: 4;
                width: 200;
                height: 30;
                focus:true;

                x:0;
                y:0;
                Node {
                    id: node;
                }
                Search {
                    id: search;
                }
                Connections {
                    id: searchconnect
                    target: search;
                    onBoxHide: {
                        suggestionBox.x = -10000;
                    }
                    onBoxUpdated: {
                        suggestionBox.height = (5-empty)*27;
                        suggestionBox.x = 0;
                        first.text = search.getSuggestions(0)
                        second.text = search.getSuggestions(1)
                        third.text = search.getSuggestions(2)
                        fourth.text = search.getSuggestions(3)
                        fith.text = search.getSuggestions(4)

                    }
                    onSpacebarPressed: {
                        selectionBox.y = selectionBox.y + 25;
                    }
                    onCycleSelection: {
                        selectionBox.y = 0;
                    }
                }
                property int xbuffer: %3;
                property int ybuffer: %4;

                TextInput {
                    id: input;
                    focus: true;
                    x:5;

                    y:5;

                    onTextChanged: {
                        search.searchBox(input.text)

                    }

                    onAccepted: {

                        node.acceptedSelection(search.getSuggestions(search.getSelection()),newrect.xbuffer,newrect.ybuffer);
                        scope.x = -400;
                        scope.y = -100;

                    }

                }
                Component.onCompleted:{
                    input.forceActiveFocus();
                }

            }
        }"




        property var dynamic_object: Qt.createQmlObject((find.arg(-300).arg(-100)).arg(-300).arg(-100),myitem,'rect')
        function create_rect(x,y){
            var xloc = x;
            var yloc = y;
            myitem.dynamic_object.destroy(0);
            myitem.dynamic_object = Qt.createQmlObject((find.arg(xloc).arg(yloc).arg(xloc).arg(yloc)),myitem,'rect');
            myitem.dynamic_object.forceActiveFocus();


        }


        }
}
```

**node.h followed by node.cpp**

```
//node.h
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Node(QObject * parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void getNode(int id);
    Q_INVOKABLE void acceptedSelection(QString selection, int x, int y);
    void generateNode(int id);
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

private:
    struct nodeInfo{
        int x;
        int y;
        QString text;
        int width;
        int height;
        int fontSize;
        int color;
        int parent;
        QVector<int> children;

    };
    QVector<nodeInfo> nodeMap;

signals:
    void createNode(QString nodeData);
public slots:
};

#endif // NODE_H

//node.cpp
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

Node::Node(QObject * parent):
    QObject (parent)
{

}

void Node::getNode(int id)
{

}

void Node::acceptedSelection(QString selection, int x, int y)
{
    if(selection=="new node"){


        nodeInfo temp;
        temp.x = y;
        temp.y = x;
        temp.width = 40;
        temp.height = 30;

        nodeMap.append(temp);
        int id = nodeMap.size() - 1;
        qDebug()<<"nodeCalled";
        QString data = "hello";
        generateNode(id);

    }

}

void Node::generateNode(int id)
{
    QString xpos = QString::number(nodeMap[id].x);
    QString ypos = QString::number(nodeMap[id].y);
    QString width = QString::number(nodeMap[id].width);
    QString height = QString::number(nodeMap[id].width);
    QString nodeData = QString("import QtQuick 2.0; Rectangle{x:%1;y:%2;width:%3;height:%4}").arg(
                xpos,ypos,width,height);
    qDebug()<<"generate called";
    emit createNode(nodeData);
}
```

**search.h followed by search.cpp**

```
#ifndef SEARCH_H
#define SEARCH_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QVector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Search:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Search(QObject * parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void searchBox(QString txt);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getSuggestions(int pos);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getSelection();

    int match(QString arg,QString reference);
    void arrange(int ar[],int ar_len);
    int suggestionsMax = 5;

private:
    QVector<QString> suggestions;
    string userFunctions[10] = {"new node","relationship","note","frame","create set","move node","format menu","copy format","paste format","zone"};
    QString inputBuffer;
    int matches[10];
    int currentSelection = 0;
    int suggestionsAvailable = 5;

signals:
    void boxUpdated(QVector<QString> suggestions,int empty);
    void boxHide();
    void spacebarPressed();
    void cycleSelection();
public slots:

};

#endif // SEARCH_H

//search.cpp
#include "search.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <node.h>

Search::Search(QObject * parent):
    QObject (parent)
{

}


//searchBox: parent function for generating suggestions in the suggestion box.
/*
 * This function is called each time the user types in a character, backspaces, or does anything to edit the text in the
 * search bar.
 *
 * input: Qstring txt
 * User input.
 *
 * Action: uses Search::match to match txt to userFunctions, sorts userFunctions in order of decreasing match value using
 * Search::arrange, appends userFunctions to suggestions array, emits signal notifying QML that suggestions has been updated.
*/
void Search::searchBox(QString txt)
{
    int txtlength = txt.size();
    int bufferlength = inputBuffer.size();
    //Compare buffer vs new input: see if user extended input or pressed backspace.
    if(txtlength>bufferlength){
        //if the user extended the input, did the user press spacebar? if yes, push selection
        if(txt[txtlength-1] == " "){
            //Has the selection reached the end of the list? if not, continue pushing selection down
            if(currentSelection<suggestionsAvailable-1){
                currentSelection+=1;
                //this signal simply tells QML to visually move the selection box.
                emit spacebarPressed();
            }
            //the selection has reached the end of the list. restart selection from 0.
            else{
                currentSelection = 0;
                //This signal tells QML to reset selection box to top position.
                emit cycleSelection();
            }
        }
        //if user continues typing after inputing spacebar, reset selection to default position
        //this means the user intended to use spacebar as spacebar rather than to cycle selection.
        else{
            emit cycleSelection();
            currentSelection = 0;
        }
    }
    //If user presses backspace, reset selection to default position
    //user doesn't want to select anything on the current list. Reset selection to default.
    else{
        emit cycleSelection();
        currentSelection = 0;
    }
    //set buffer in preparation for next call. Reset empty to default value.
    inputBuffer = txt;
    int empty = 0;

    //is there anything in txt? if yes, begin analyzing txt.
    if(txtlength!=0){
        int n = sizeof(userFunctions)/sizeof(*userFunctions);

        //see how much txt matches with each userFunction. Values stored in matches[]
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            matches[i]=match(txt,QString::fromStdString(userFunctions[i]));
        }
        //arrange in order of descent; greatest first.
        arrange(matches,n);
        //Reset suggestions from previous appends.
        suggestions = {};

        //Select first 5 suggestions to place on suggest box.
        //This works because suggestions are already ordered from best match to least match.
        //If first five contains suggestions that are low match, exclude these.
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            if(matches[i]>5){
                suggestions.append(QString::fromStdString(userFunctions[i]));
            }
            else{
                empty+=1;
                suggestions.append("");
            }

        }
        suggestionsAvailable = suggestionsMax-empty;
        emit boxUpdated(suggestions,empty);
    }
    //if user preses backspace and clears the search box: clear suggestions
    else{
        suggestions = {"","","","",""};
        empty = suggestionsMax;
        suggestionsAvailable = 0;
        emit boxUpdated(suggestions,empty);
        emit boxHide();
    }
}

int Search::getSelection()
{
    return(currentSelection);
}

//This function swaps values held by two pointers.
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

/*
 * Sorting algorithm. selective sorting method
 * Sorts provided array in descending magnitude. The sorting of userFunctions is coupled to this process.
*/
void Search::arrange(int ar[],int ar_len)
{
    int n = ar_len;

    int flag  = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++){
        flag = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(ar[j]>ar[flag]){
                flag=j;
            }
        }
        swap(&ar[flag],&ar[i]);
        string temp;
        temp = userFunctions[flag];
        userFunctions[flag] = userFunctions[i];
        userFunctions[i] = temp;
    }


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        matches[i] = ar[i];
    }
}

//fetches suggestions. Called from QML.
QString Search::getSuggestions(int pos)
{
    return suggestions[pos];
}


//This function takes two strings, and sees how much the first string matches the second string.
/*
 * input: string1, string2
 * output: integer
 *
 * The higher the integer, the higher the match.
*/
int Search::match(QString arg,QString reference)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int l = arg.size();
    \
    QStringList split;
    for(int i=l; i>0; i--){
        QString sub = arg.mid(0,i);
        \
        if(reference.contains(sub)){
            temp+=i*i;
        }
        split = reference.split(" ");
        int s = split.size();
      \
        for(int j=0; j<s; j++){

            QString spsub = split[j].mid(0,i);
            if(sub==spsub){

                temp+=i*i;
                if(j==0){
                    temp+=5;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include <search.h>
#include <node.h>




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<Search>("Search",1,0,"Search");
    qmlRegisterType<Node>("Node",1,0,"Node");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
``
```

Comment: Please, provide a complete and minimal example

Comment: Sorry, first time, added full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your `Node` dynamically through `find` property of ***myitem***. There is not a connection to that Node. It's a different Node than what you expect to emit that signal.

Here is the `find` property to test if the signal is triggered :

```
   property string find:"
        import QtQuick 2.0
        import Search 1.0
        import Node 1.0
        FocusScope{
            id: scope;
            focus:true;
            x:%1;
            y:%2;

            Rectangle {
                id: suggestionBox;
                color: 'grey';
                border.width:2;
                width:200;
                height:135;
                x:-5000
                y:34
                Text {
                    id: first;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 5;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: second;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 30;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: third;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 55;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: fourth;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 80;
                    text: '';
                }
                Text {
                    id: fith;
                    x: 5;
                    y: 105;
                    text: '';
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: selectionBox;
                    color:'#33000000';
                    border.width:2;
                    width: 200;
                    height:25;
                    x: 0;
                    y: 0;
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id:newrect;
                color: 'grey';
                border.width: 4;
                width: 200;
                height: 30;
                focus:true;

                x:0;
                y:0;
                Node {
                    id: node;


                }
                Search {
                    id: search;
                }
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// HERE I ADDED THE CONNECTION TO TEST THE SIGNAL
////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Connections {
            id: nodeconnect;
            target: node;
            onCreateNode:{
                console.log(\"hi\");
            }
        }

                Connections {
                    id: searchconnect
                    target: search;
                    onBoxHide: {
                        suggestionBox.x = -10000;
                    }
                    onBoxUpdated: {
                        suggestionBox.height = (5-empty)*27;
                        suggestionBox.x = 0;
                        first.text = search.getSuggestions(0)
                        second.text = search.getSuggestions(1)
                        third.text = search.getSuggestions(2)
                        fourth.text = search.getSuggestions(3)
                        fith.text = search.getSuggestions(4)

                    }
                    onSpacebarPressed: {
                        selectionBox.y = selectionBox.y + 25;
                    }
                    onCycleSelection: {
                        selectionBox.y = 0;
                    }
                }
                property int xbuffer: %3;
                property int ybuffer: %4;

                TextInput {
                    id: input;
                    focus: true;
                    x:5;

                    y:5;

                    onTextChanged: {
                        search.searchBox(input.text)

                    }

                    onAccepted: {

                        node.acceptedSelection(search.getSuggestions(search.getSelection()),newrect.xbuffer,newrect.ybuffer);
                        scope.x = -400;
                        scope.y = -100;

                    }

                }
                Component.onCompleted:{
                    input.forceActiveFocus();
                }

            }
        }"
```

Comment: I see... Will try when I get back. Thanks!